# How to iterate object using typescript

Tags: typescript

Iam new in typescript language I tried to iterate the object using typescript. but it's throwing an error how to handle this error.
**[typescript] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }' has no index signature.**

**Code**

```
var obj = {
  a: ' a',
  b: 'b ',
  c: ' c '
};

Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k] = obj[k].trim());
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating an interface for your variable `obj`, such that TypeScript compiler will know the typings of your keys/properties and values.

```
interface TheObject {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const obj: TheObject = {
  a: ' a',
  b: 'b ',
  c: ' c '
};
```

The reason why the following error (`[typescript] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }' has no index signature.`) is showing is because TypeScript is unaware of the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) since your original `obj` is not typed, hence it was defined as `any`, which means it might not be iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate object using for in loop like this

```
for (var key in obj){
    obj[key] = obj[key].trim()
    console.log(obj[key])
}
```